# Как правильно написать триггер на сумму чисел строки при появлении новой записи?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Нужен триггер, который, будет вписывать все поля с DECIMAL  сумму в ячейку 'outcome'

```
CREATE TABLE maintable_pricetable (
id           INTEGER       NOT NULL
                           PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
transparency DECIMAL       NOT NULL,
color        DECIMAL       NOT NULL,
pis          DECIMAL       NOT NULL,
purity       DECIMAL       NOT NULL,
intensity    DECIMAL       NOT NULL,
typicality   DECIMAL       NOT NULL,
purity2      DECIMAL       NOT NULL,
intensity2   DECIMAL       NOT NULL,
persistence  DECIMAL       NOT NULL,
typicality2  DECIMAL       NOT NULL,
description  VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
taster       VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
date         VARCHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
harmony      DECIMAL       NOT NULL,
outcome      VARCHAR (20),
сipher       VARCHAR (6)   NOT NULL);
```

Пример как будет выглядеть в живую. Триггер должен вписать это в 'Итог' aka 'outcome'
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Простая генерация не подойдет**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как пример: ( необходимые поля суммы можно добавить самому )

[подробнее про триггеры SQLite](https://zametkinapolyah.ru/zametki-o-mysql/tema-13-triggery-v-sql-na-primere-bazy-dannyx-sqlite.html)

```
-- триггер будет срабатывать после обновления строки и складывать результат в ячейку outcome
CREATE TRIGGER maintable_pricetable_sum_tr AFTER UPDATE  ON maintable_pricetable

BEGIN
    UPDATE maintable_pricetable 
    SET outcome = NEW.purity + NEW.intensity + NEW.typicality + NEW.purity2 -- и т.д
    WHERE id= NEW.id;

END
```

---

P.S.

*Небольшое примечание ( возможно ошибаюсь, давно триггеры писал для SQLlite )*

*Не знаю точно нужно и можно ли указывать конкретные столбцы на которые должен срабатывать триггер, так как в других СУБД, можно нарваться на рекурсию
из-за того что триггер делает изменение в таблице на которую повешен триггер*

*Вроде потестил, проблем не было.*

Comment: я бы поставил на before - и сразу заполнял поле

Comment: @louis, Благодарю!